# R: "raster" cannot read a GeoTIFF that "readGDAL" is able to read

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp, rgdal

**Question**:

I'm working with MODIS GeoTIFFs. I want to use the `sf` and `raster` libraries. The file easily opens with `rgdal::readGDAL()`, which gives me an object of type `Large SpatialGridDataFrame`. So the file is not corrupt.

Yet, if I use `raster` I get the following error:

```
raster::raster("../MCD64A1/TIFF/Win09/2014/MCD64monthly.A2014001.Win09.006.burndate.tif")
  Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

**More background info**:

The same happens if I use `raster::stack`.

For reproduction: the file can be found in the [MODIS](https://modis-fire.umd.edu/ba.html)-collection or be directly downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1p5gpj1uabigrv0/MCD64monthly.A2014001.Win09.006.burndate.tif?dl=0). Relevant package versions are:

```
 [1] raster_3.4-13 rgeos_0.5-8   sf_0.9-8      rgdal_1.5-27  sp_1.4-2      RNetCDF_2.5-2
```

**Edit**:

It seems `raster` hides some error message. Calling the internal `.rasterFromGDAP` directly reveals the error message. Though the fix remains unclear:

```
> raster:::.rasterFromGDAL("../MCD64A1/TIFF/Win09/2014
/MCD64monthly.A2014001.Win09.006.burndate.tif", type = "RasterLayer",band=1)
Error in CRS(crs, TRUE) : 
  PROJ4 argument-value pairs must begin with +: GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not get this error.

```
library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
f <- "MCD64monthly.A2014001.Win09.006.burndate.tif"
b <- raster(f)
b
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 8533, 5461, 46598713  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.004394531, 0.004394531  (x, y)
#extent     : -19, 4.998535, 0.001464844, 37.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : MCD64monthly.A2014001.Win09.006.burndate.tif 
#names      : MCD64monthly.A2014001.Win09.006.burndate 
#min values :                                   -32768 
#max values :                                    32767 

sessionInfo()
# ...
#other attached packages:
#[1] raster_3.4-13 sp_1.4-5     
#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#[1] compiler_4.1.0   rgdal_1.5-27     tools_4.1.0      Rcpp_1.0.7       codetools_0.2-18 grid_4.1.0       #lattice_0.20-44
```

I think it will go away for you as well after you update the `sp` package. When things do not work, it is good practice to first assure you have the latest versions of the R packages (perhaps run `update.packages(ask=FALSE)` )